# Handling IOExceptions in Android

Tags: java, android, exception, ioexception

I'm creating an app where I need a function to get plain text from a website. I am able to get the text and print it out on my PC just fine, but when I try running it on an Android device, the app won't start.

I believe it has something to do with throwing an IOException. I've been reading that I am not supposed to do that because I don't define the interface. Is there a way to get around this? Android Studio won't compile my code if I don't throw the exception.

The function:

```
public String getText(String site) throws IOException {
    // Make a URL to the web page
    URL url = new URL(site);

    // Get the input stream through URL Connection
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // read each line and return the final text
    String res = "";
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);
        res += line;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And this is how Android Studio makes me run it in the onCreate method:

```
String text = null;
    try {
        text = getText("http://myWebsite.com");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Classic anti-pattern. Code that relies on the success of code in a try block should be in the same try block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read your logcat - you should see your exception there with full stacktrace. Second, there is nothing wrong with catching IOException, but you must do something with it once cached - like inform user of problem in functionality - like no more space, etc.

> And this is how Android Studio makes me run it in the onCreate method:

this is a problem, because your are getting data from your site on UI thread, you must do it from worker thread, ie. AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it in the main thread

try this

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        private String site;

        MyTask(String site) {
            this.site = site;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(site);
                URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                // read each line and return the final text
                String res = "";
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    //System.out.println(line);
                    res += line;
                }
                return res;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s != null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

where to get a string is used as

```
new MyTask("http://myWebsite.com").execute()
```